# Apple Watch WCConnectionDelegate, sending message in activationDidComplete fails occasionally?

Tags: swift, watchkit, wcsession

I am having an issue where, when sending a message through WCConnection, the `session.sendMessage` fails sometimes if called in the delegate method `activationDidCompleteWith`. The issue is not repeatable every time (in fact, it works most of the time).

But forcing a `session.sendMessage` by using a button in my UI (calling the identical loading code) has a successful session communication immediately, so I know the issue is not in the session itself or the master app.

Is it unsafe to assume the session is ready to accept communication in `activationDidCompleteWith`? Is there a better place to be calling my initial communication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience watch OS is pretty finicky, especially when using older model watches. That being said I think the answer to the question: "Is it unsafe to assume the session is ready to accept communication in activationDidCompleteWith?" is yes, it is unsafe to assume that.

In my own app I have a very similar case to yours and I solved it by sending a message until a response is received.

```
    // false until a response is received from the phone
    let receivedResponse: Bool = false 

    // function that sends the message
    func requestResponse() {
        guard WCSession.default.isReachable else {
            print("Phone not reachable")
            return
        }

        // callback that handles response
        let responseHandler: ([String: Any]) -> () = { response in
            receivedResponse = true
            callback(response)
        }

        WCSession.default.sendMessage(["Request": "Response"],
                                      replyHandler: responseHandler) { error in
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }

    // timer that calls the request function repeatedly
    let retryTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1,
                                          repeats: true) { timer in
        if receivedResponse {
            // we know we got a response so clean up timer
            timer.invalidate()
        }
        requestResponse()
    }
```

Comment: I actually ended up doing something similar and it works great, thank you for the answer!